# knn classifier with own distance function

Tags: matlab, knn, pdist

I am using a Knn classifier in MATLAB. Here is my Code:

```
load fisheriris
x = meas(:,3:4);

newpoint = [5 1.45];

[n,d] = knnsearch(x,newpoint,'k',10, 'Distance', 'euclidean');
```

Now I would like to use my own distance function. To be sure, that it is working,
I first would like to define my "own" Euclidean distance. After that I would like to
try the ChiSquare Distance.

My problem: How can I create my own distance function. I know I should use `pdist()`, but I am not able to get it working. Would be great to get some hints.

Comment: This is pretty self-explanatory. I do not have MATLAB access to write a short code. From MATLAB documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html)`custom distance function — A distance function specified using @ (for example, @distfun). A distance function must be of the form function D2 = distfun(ZI, ZJ), taking as arguments a 1-by-n vector ZI containing a single row of X or Y, an m2-by-n matrix ZJ containing multiple rows of X or Y, and returning an m2-by-1 vector of distances D2, whose jth element is the distance between the observations ZI and ZJ(j,:).`

Comment: try it and if you have problems then post it here.